# VBA Paste PDF onto powerpoint terrible quality

Tags: vba, pdf, powerpoint

I wrote a macro to paste a PDF into a powerpoint using the AddOLEObject function. It works as intended except for there being a huge loss of quality of the image. The PDF is a single 8.5x11 page of a few graphs generated by flow cytometry software (if anyone is familiar). When pasted, some of the axis and tickers are missing as well as fragments of letters and numbers. This is obviously undesirable.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
Set FlowScript2 = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With FlowScript2
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "PDFs", "*.pdf"
    .Title = "Select Lentivirus Transduction Flow Results File"
    .Show
End With

If FlowScript2.SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then

    FlowFile =Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker).SelectedItems(1)

    Set shp = sld.Shapes.AddOLEObject(Left:=50.4, Top:=110, Width:=792, Height:=612, FileName:=FlowFile, Link:=False)
    shp.Line.Visible = msoTrue

    With shp.PictureFormat
        .CropLeft = 45
        .CropRight = 45
        .CropTop = 52
        .CropBottom = 210
    End With

End If
```

I have tried to paste the image at different sizes, which has not worked. I read somewhere that it might be better to use Adobe objects, however I am looking to distribute the end result to other users and am worried that the version may not be ubiquitous. At a loss of what to do. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the document with an icon, and then place an ActiveX picture in front of the icon, then create and attach your own optimized image for the picture to the ActiveX Picture property.

And finally, attach some code to the click event of the ActiveX control:

```
Private Sub Image1_Click()
  Dim shp As Shape
  Set shp = Slide1.Shapes("Object 1")
  shp.OLEFormat.DoVerb 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @ThunderFrame, thank you for your post. This is a great suggestion, but I would like to avoid having to generate separate images as I don't think users would be willing to do it. Are there any other methods for handling PDFs?

Comment: I don't think VBA lets you determine the quality, and the scaling is clearly problematic. The other (uglier) alternative is to add the PDF as an icon, and then set the background of the shape - but the icon is still visible in front of the shape. I don't know how much time/energy you have, but you could look into automating the creation of PDF thumbnails and then use those with the approach mentioned in my main answer.